# How should I go about finding a UX mentor?

Tags: career-development, learning

There seems to be a lot of evidence that having a mentor is crucial to career success and even more important when transitioning between careers. I've read that social networking sites - twitter & linked are good resources for the same, but I haven't had good luck with it. So, how do I find a UX professional that is willing to mentor me? Does someone here have time for a protege?

Comment: The UX Mastery Forum has a specific 'Mentoring' section - http://community.uxmastery.com/forum/mentoring - that might be useful. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A mentor can be invaluable, but in my experience, those relationships emerge as the result of further developing professional relationships. LinkedIn and Twitter are great for networking, and if you use them to follow professionals and engage in ongoing dialog they can also be useful for professional development. But the kind of extended guidance of mentorship generaly requires more of a direct personal relationship.

I would suggest that your best bet here is to look around your current workplace and see if there is someone there doing UX that you have a lot of respect for. If so, think about how you can start to ask them for guidance. If there isn't anyone in your current work place I'd suggest trying to find face-to-face meetups and events in your area where you can start to connect with other folks in the field.

Comment: Agree with Trevor, some great communities that you can look into is the UPA - they have chapters everywhere, if you're in the States - highly likely they have a chapter in your area. Another organization is IXDA and they actually do address this question of mentorship, I believe they have some programs/help associated with it. Worth checking it out.

Comment: Trevor - I think you are right. I might have better luck pursuing direct relationships.

Comment: Firedrawndagger - I'll try IxDa.

Comment: It's too bad their mentee site is down http://www.ixda.org/mentee.php